# Create a multilingual calendar in php - 'translating' with setlocale

Tags: php, wordpress, localization, locale

I am creating an hourly calendar (a booking form), and I have my calendar created

```
    $today = time();

    if (date('D', $today) === 'Mon') {
        $timestamp = strtotime('this Monday');
    } else{
        $timestamp = strtotime('last Monday');
    }

    $days = array();
    $dates = array();

    for ($i = 0; $i < 7; $i++) {
        $days[] = strftime('%A <br /> %d %b %Y', $timestamp);
        $dates[] = strftime('%d %b %Y', $timestamp);
        $timestamp = strtotime('+1 day', $timestamp);
    }

        $return .= '<table class="reservation_time_table">
                        <tr><th>'.esc_html__('Hours', 'time_reservation').'</th>';
            foreach ($days as $day => $day_value) {
                $today_class = ( strtotime(gmdate('d M Y', $today)) == strtotime(strip_tags($day_value)) ) ? 'class="today"' : '';
                $return .= '<th '.$today_class.'>'.$day_value.'</th>';
            }
            $return .= '</tr>';
            for ($hour=8; $hour < 23 ; $hour++) {
            $return .= '<tr>';
                $return .= '<th>'.$hour.':00</th>';
            foreach ($dates as $date => $date_value) {
                $full_hour = $hour. ':00';
                $table_date = strtotime($date_value. ' ' .$full_hour);
                $reserved = (in_array($table_date, $full_reserved_array)) ? 'disabled' : '';
                $disabled_class = ($today > $table_date) ? 'disabled' : '';
                $return .= '<td class="reservation_time '. $disabled_class. ' '. $reserved .'" data-time="'.$table_date.'"></td>';
            }
            $return .= '</tr>';
            }
        $return .= '</table>';
```

I have an array of booked dates in my `$reserved` variable.

Now since the site I'm working on is build on wordpress and translated with WPML, I can check the language of the site like:

```
if( in_array('sitepress-multilingual-cms/sitepress.php', get_option('active_plugins')) ){
    $current_lang = ICL_LANGUAGE_CODE;
} else{
    $current_lang = '';
}
```

So for instance for Swedish this will be `sv`, for German `de` etc.

So I googled a bit, and what I found is that I can change the format of my time and dates by using `setlocale()`. So I tried:

```
if ($current_lang == 'sv') {
    setlocale(LC_ALL, 'sv-SE');
} elseif($current_lang == 'de') {
    setlocale(LC_ALL, 'de-DE');
} else{
    setlocale(LC_ALL, 'en-US');
}
```

I also tried with just:

```
setlocale(LC_TIME, 'sv-SE');
```

But nothing changed on my frontend.

I tried putting my `if-else` loop with `$timestamp` inside (and even changed the name to match the translation), I put the `for` loop in, but nothing changed.

How do I handle the translation when building calendar with php?

Comment: If I don't have proper locales installed on the server than the translation won't work, right? Because that could be the case. I checked with `locale -a` and all I had were the same as [here](http://askubuntu.com/questions/76013/how-do-i-add-locale-to-ubuntu-server)

Answer (score 0):

Ok, so the answer is that I was missing the proper locale. But that just points out the bigger issue - if the server I deploy this won't have it it won't be ok.

So the solution is to install the proper localization on server

```
sudo locale-gen sv_SE
sudo locale-gen sv_SE.UTF-8
```

or whatever language you need...